# magento 404 edit page not found

Tags: php, magento-1.9

I have a grid which loads my items, and it's working properly but when I click on the item it should redirect to my edit page, but somehow it gives my 404 NOT FOUND. Am I missing something?

here's my **config.xml** :

```
<config>

<modules>
    <Mjsi_Walmartapi>
        <version>0.0.1</version>
    </Mjsi_Walmartapi>
</modules>

<global>
    <models>
        <Walmartapi>
            <class>Mjsi_Walmartapi_Model</class>
            <resourceModel>Walmartapi_resource</resourceModel>
        </Walmartapi>
        <Walmartapi_resource>
            <class>Mjsi_Walmartapi_Model_Resource</class>
            <entities>
                <item>
                    <table>Walmartapi_item</table>
                </item>
                <order>
                    <table>Walmartapi_order</table>
                </order>
            </entities>
        </Walmartapi_resource>
    </models>
    <resources>
        <walmart_setup>
            <setup>
                <module>Mjsi_Walmartapi</module>
                <class>Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup</class>
            </setup>
        </walmart_setup>
    </resources>
    <blocks>
        <Walmartapi>
            <class>Mjsi_Walmartapi_Block</class>
        </Walmartapi>
    </blocks>
    <helpers>
        <Walmartapi>
            <class>Mjsi_Walmartapi_Helper</class>
        </Walmartapi>
    </helpers>
    <events>
        <controller_action_predispatch>
            <observers>
                <Walmartapi_observer>
                    <class>Walmartapi/observer</class>
                    <method>controllerActionPredispatch</method>
                </Walmartapi_observer>
            </observers>
        </controller_action_predispatch>
    </events>
</global>
<admin>
    <routers>
        <adminhtml>
            <args>
                <modules>
                    <Walmartapi before="Mage_Adminhtml">Mjsi_Walmartapi_Adminhtml</Walmartapi>
                </modules>
            </args>
        </adminhtml>
    </routers>
</admin>
```

here's my **adminhtml.xml** :

```
 <acl>
    <resources>
        <all>
            <title>Allow Everything</title>
        </all>
        <admin>
            <children>
                <system>
                    <children>
                        <config>
                            <children>
                                <walmart>
                                    <title>Walmartapi</title>
                                </walmart>
                            </children>
                        </config>
                    </children>
                </system>
                <Walmartapi translate="title" module="Walmartapi">
                    <title>Walmartapi</title>
                    <children>
                        <item translate="title" module="Walmartapi">
                            <title>Product</title>
                            <sort_order>0</sort_order>
                        </item>
                        <order translate="title" module="Walmartapi">
                            <title>Order</title>
                            <sort_order>10</sort_order>
                        </order>
                        <choose translate="title" module="Walmartapi">
                            <title>Choose</title>
                            <sort_order>15</sort_order>
                        </choose>
                    </children>
                </Walmartapi>
            </children>
        </admin>
    </resources>
</acl>

<menu>
    <Walmartapi translate="title" module="Walmartapi">
        <title>Walmart</title>
        <sort_order>1000</sort_order>
        <children>
            <item translate="title" module="Walmartapi">
                <title>Manage Items</title>
                <action>adminhtml/walmartapi_item</action>
                <sort_order>0</sort_order>
            </item>
            <order translate="title" module="Walmartapi">
                <title>Orders</title>
                <action>adminhtml/walmartapi_order</action>
                <sort_order>10</sort_order>
            </order>
            <choose translate="title" module="Walmartapi">
                <title>Choose Item</title>
                <action>adminhtml/walmartapi_choose</action>
                <sort_order>15</sort_order>
            </choose>
        </children>
    </Walmartapi>
</menu>
```

here's my **ChooseController.php** :

```
class Mjsi_Walmartapi_Adminhtml_Walmartapi_ChooseController extends Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_Action
{

public function indexAction()
{
    $this->loadLayout();

    $this->_addContent($this->getLayout()->createBlock('Walmartapi/adminhtml_choose'));

    return $this->renderLayout();
}
}
```

here's my **Grid.php** :

```
<?php

class Mjsi_Walmartapi_Block_Adminhtml_Choose_Grid extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid
{
    public function getRowUrl($item)
    {
        return $this->getUrl('*/walmartapi_choose/edit', array('item_id' => $item->getId()));
    }

    protected function _getStore()
    {
        $storeId = (int) $this->getRequest()->getParam('store', 0);
        return Mage::app()->getStore($storeId);
    }

    protected function _prepareCollection()
    {
        $walmartProduct = Mage::getModel("Walmartapi/item")->getCollection();
        $walmartProduct->getSelect()
        ->reset(Zend_Db_Select::COLUMNS)
        ->columns(array('sku',));

        foreach ($walmartProduct as $item) {
            $walmartItem[] = $item->getData();
        }

        $store = $this->_getStore();
        $collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()
            ->addAttributeToSelect('sku')
            ->addAttributeToSelect('name')
            ->addAttributeToSelect('attribute_set_id')
            ->addAttributeToSelect('type_id');

        if (Mage::helper('catalog')->isModuleEnabled('Mage_CatalogInventory')) {
            $collection->joinField(
                'qty',
                'cataloginventory/stock_item',
                'qty',
                'product_id=entity_id',
                '{{table}}.stock_id=1',
                'left'
            );
        }
        if ($store->getId()) {
            //$collection->setStoreId($store->getId());
            $adminStore = Mage_Core_Model_App::ADMIN_STORE_ID;
            $collection->addStoreFilter($store);
            $collection->joinAttribute(
                'name',
                'catalog_product/name',
                'entity_id',
                null,
                'inner',
                $adminStore
            );
            $collection->joinAttribute(
                'price',
                'catalog_product/price',
                'entity_id',
                null,
                'left',
                $store->getId()
            );
        } else {
            $collection->addAttributeToSelect('price');
        }

        $this->setCollection($collection);

        for ($i=0; $i < count($walmartItem); $i++) {
            $collection->addAttributeToFilter('sku', array('nlike' => $walmartItem[$i]));
        }

        parent::_prepareCollection();
        return parent::_prepareCollection();
    }

    protected function _prepareColumns()
    {

        $this->addColumn(
            'name',
            array(
                'header'=> Mage::helper('catalog')->__('Name'),
                'index' => 'name',
            )
        );

        $store = $this->_getStore();
        if ($store->getId()) {
            $this->addColumn(
                'custom_name',
                array(
                    'header'=> Mage::helper('catalog')->__('Name in %s', $this->escapeHtml($store->getName())),
                    'index' => 'custom_name',
                )
            );
        }

        $this->addColumn(
            'sku',
            array(
                'header'=> Mage::helper('catalog')->__('SKU'),
                'width' => '80px',
                'index' => 'sku',
            )
        );

        $store = $this->_getStore();
        $this->addColumn(
            'price',
            array(
                'header'=> Mage::helper('catalog')->__('Price'),
                'type'  => 'price',
                'currency_code' => $store->getBaseCurrency()->getCode(),
                'index' => 'price',
            )
        );

        if (Mage::helper('catalog')->isModuleEnabled('Mage_CatalogInventory')) {
            $this->addColumn(
                'qty',
                array(
                    'header'=> Mage::helper('catalog')->__('Qty'),
                    'width' => '100px',
                    'type'  => 'number',
                    'index' => 'qty',
                )
            );
        }
        ;

        if (Mage::helper('catalog')->isModuleEnabled('Mage_Rss')) {
            $this->addRssList('rss/catalog/notifystock', Mage::helper('catalog')->__('Notify Low Stock RSS'));
        }

        return $this;
    }
}
```

here's my **Edit.php** :

```
<?php

class Mjsi_Walmartapi_Block_Adminhtml_Choose_Edit extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Form_Container
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->_objectId = 'item_id';
        $this->_blockGroup = 'Walmartapi';
        $this->_controller = 'adminhtml_choose';

        parent::__construct();
    }

    public function getHeaderText()
    {
        return Mage::helper('Walmartapi')->__('Edits Item');
    }

    public function getSaveUrl()
    {
        return $this->getUrl('*/walmartapi_choose/save', array('_current' => true));
    }
}
```

here's my **Form.php** :

```
<?php

class Mjsi_Walmartapi_Block_Adminhtml_Choose_Edit_Form extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Form
{
    protected function _initFormValues()
    {
        if ($item = Mage::registry('current_item')) {
            $data = $item->getData();
            $this->getForm()->setValues($data);
        }

        if ($data = Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->getData('item_form_data', true)) {
            $this->getForm()->setValues($data);
        }
    }

    protected function _prepareForm()
    {
        $form = new Varien_Data_Form(
            array('id' => 'edit_form', 'action' => $this->getData('action'), 'method' => 'post')
        );

        $fieldset = $form->addFieldset('base_fieldset', array('legend' => Mage::helper('Walmartapi')->__('Add New Item')));

        $fieldset->addField('mart', 'text', array(
            'name'      => 'mart',
            'label'     => Mage::helper('Walmartapi')->__('Mart'),
            'title'     => Mage::helper('Walmartapi')->__('Mart'),
            'required'  => true
        ));

        $fieldset->addField('sku', 'text', array(
            'name'      => 'sku',
            'label'     => Mage::helper('Walmartapi')->__('SKU'),
            'title'     => Mage::helper('Walmartapi')->__('SKU'),
            'required'  => true
        ));

        $fieldset->addField('wpid', 'text', array(
            'name'      => 'wpid',
            'label'     => Mage::helper('Walmartapi')->__('Walmart Product ID'),
            'title'     => Mage::helper('Walmartapi')->__('Walmart Product ID'),
            'required'  => true
        ));

        $fieldset->addField('upc', 'text', array(
            'name'      => 'upc',
            'label'     => Mage::helper('Walmartapi')->__('UPC'),
            'title'     => Mage::helper('Walmartapi')->__('UPC'),
            'required'  => true
        ));

        $fieldset->addField('gtin', 'text', array(
            'name'      => 'gtin',
            'label'     => Mage::helper('Walmartapi')->__('GTIN'),
            'title'     => Mage::helper('Walmartapi')->__('GTIN'),
            'required'  => true
        ));

        $fieldset->addField('product_name', 'text', array(
            'name'      => 'product_name',
            'label'     => Mage::helper('Walmartapi')->__('Product Name'),
            'title'     => Mage::helper('Walmartapi')->__('Product Name'),
            'required'  => true
        ));

        $fieldset->addField('product_type', 'text', array(
            'name'      => 'product_type',
            'label'     => Mage::helper('Walmartapi')->__('Product Type'),
            'title'     => Mage::helper('Walmartapi')->__('Product Type'),
            'required'  => true
        ));

        $fieldset->addField('currency', 'text', array(
            'name'      => 'currency',
            'label'     => Mage::helper('Walmartapi')->__('Currency'),
            'title'     => Mage::helper('Walmartapi')->__('Currency'),
            'required'  => true
        ));

        $fieldset->addField('amount', 'text', array(
            'name'      => 'amount',
            'label'     => Mage::helper('Walmartapi')->__('Amount'),
            'title'     => Mage::helper('Walmartapi')->__('Amount'),
            'required'  => true
        ));

        $fieldset->addField('quantity', 'text', array(
            'name'      => 'quantity',
            'label'     => Mage::helper('Walmartapi')->__('Quantity'),
            'title'     => Mage::helper('Walmartapi')->__('Quantity'),
            'required'  => true
        ));

        $fieldset->addField('published_status', 'text', array(
            'name'      => 'published_status',
            'label'     => Mage::helper('Walmartapi')->__('Publish Status'),
            'title'     => Mage::helper('Walmartapi')->__('Publish Status'),
            'required'  => true
        ));

        $form->setUseContainer(true);
        $this->setForm($form);
    }
}
```

here's the screenshot :
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JJICM.png)

Comment: How does the URL you are redirected to look like?

Comment: @ManuelArwedSchmidt it redirects me to a 404 page not found. I've added a screenshot.